# Are vague variable names more maintainable?

Tags: c#, design, clean-code, maintainability

I'm looking for some advice about which line of code is more appropriate, readable, and maintainable.

## 1:

```
var result = mediator.Send(query).Result;
```

## 2:

```
var accountDetails = mediator.Send(accountFilter).Result;
```

The above code was taken from a Web API controller. The pros for each:

## 1:

- If the query needs to change and return a different type, we don't have to remember to rename the result variable.
- That also means code reviews won't be polluted with a bunch of files that have changed due to the renaming.
- The job of a Web API controller isn't to know the details about what business logic is going on; it's just to invoke something and return it.
- If you really want to know what the line of code is doing, you can look at the context surrounding it.

## 2:

- It's easier to look at the line of code and understand what the line of code is doing.

Comment: Code is more often read than written. So make it as readable as you can.

Comment: The single bullet point in #2 is more important than everything in #1 combined.

Comment: If vague names truly were better, wouldn't we name everything "a", "it", or "thingie"?

Comment: "If the query needs to change and return a different type, we don't have to remember to rename the result variable." <- Most people put bread in their toaster and make toast. I put input in my appliance and get output. That way I don't have to remember to rename it if I replace my toaster with a waffle iron.

Comment: This is a loaded question. From the way you worded the question, it's obvious that you are already set on expecting a particular answer.

Comment: @LieRyan If you could suggest a better way to word it, I'd be happy to use it. And yes, I do believe #2 is the way to go, but I'm looking for good thoughts on why I might be wrong.

Comment: Let me give you an example of how much more maintainable they are... we had to adjust a few things in an old program that was written about five years ago or so (by someone who already left the company). Apparently he had the same idea as yours about variable naming, everything was generic. So we spent nearly an entire week fixing their names and trying to crack how this damn thing worked. We managed to make it pretty and understandable for anyone at last but wasted a week on doing only that and haven't done any adjustments yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer:
No, vague names are far less maintainable than precise names. You won't rename things on a weekly basis (and if you do, you should ask yourself "What is the reason for this"). Changing the result type is a rather big change, so if I were to get a `detailProxyBroker` instead of the real `accountDetails` it would be kinda neat to know that at first glance...

Be as precise as you need be, so it you (or any random stranger who joins your team) can read & understand the code.

I would have a hard time to imagine what `var result` is I get from`mediator.Send(query).Result;`

`var accountDetails` I get from `mediator.Send(accountFilter).Result;` is much easier to understand. You do not need to include in the variable name that the accountDetails hold Name, Birthday and favorite colour - that is too much detail.

Heck, if not needing to change names is your goal just call it `var a = b.Send(c).Result;` you can stuff whatever you want in `a`, `b` and `c`... :/

So, to wrap it up, use variant (2) - your coworker (and you yourself) will be glad to have (nearly) self-documenting code, when you need to work with that piece of code again in X weeks.

Comment: Any decent IDE will tell you at a glance what the type of `var result` is.  That said, if `var result` is being used in a code block that's more than a few lines long, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So if you use the IDE to hover over the variable to see what it is, that means you wanted to know what it was. So why not name it something explicit so you don't even need to hover? Isn't it appropriate for code to read like a book, where you don't need to pause and figure stuff out along the way?

Comment: @BobHorn yes it is just like a book, with footnotes or further reading. Most of the time, the prose is enough. Need more details? Refer to the footnotes. Likewise `var` should be adequate for most of the time. Occasionally you’ll need the extra detail and then the hover “footnotes” comes into play. That way the code isn’t cluttered with more detail than is needed for most of the time.

Comment: Not all code is read in an IDE though, so if you need one to understand your code you’re probably on a bad path

Comment: @axl seriously, when did you last look at code outside an IDE? Use the tools; don’t fight them.

Comment: When I was browsing code diffs in git five minutes ago

Comment: @axl and you seriously needed to know the types behind those vars when looking at a diff? No, of course not. The whole point re my footnote analogy is that you rarely need to know the type to understand the code, so that hovering over a var is a rare event. If you constantly need to know the type, then you are genuinely in a bad place with bad code to boot.

Comment: @Bob Horn I like the book & footnote example. The naming should be precise enough to give the read a good idea what is going on (without needing to reference 20+ pages), but including footnotes (i.e. the IDE's tooltip) to give additional details if so desired (without directly adding to the current chapter a George R.R. Martin-esque 5-page description of the food-spread on the table)

Comment: If the code is written well, you should rarely care about the actual variable type.  The compiler will yell at you if you screw up your types.  As a developer, focus on getting your business logic right.  That means things like 'WeeklyEarnings = HourlyWage * HoursWorked'.  Most of the time, you don't care if those are all int, double, or float.

Comment: @DavidArno I wasn’t referring to your comment, just the often brought up idea that an IDE could be a substitute for good naming and structuring. I would hate to have to work without an IDE, but I would also hate not being able to make any sense of code without one. And no, I don’t think the exact type is important most of the time. So I think we’re actually in agreement.

Answer (score 12):

IMHO most of your "pro" arguments are flawed, but let us discuss them one-by-one:

> If the query needs to change and return a different type, we don't have to remember to rename the result variable.

If the query returns a different type in such a way that a name like `accountDetails` does not fit any more, the code depending on that variable will have to be changed, even if the variable name is just `result`. This is definitely easier (and thus less error prone) when the variable has a specific name. The only exception here is IMHO when there is no such code, like in a function where the `result` is just returned to the caller.

> That also means code reviews won't be polluted with a bunch of files that have changed due to the renaming.

If you start arguing that way, you should never ever rename any variable in your code, regardless of how badly the name was chosen, just to make code reviews more effective. Maybe you should never do any refactorings? But then don't be astonished when your code quality degrades every day.

Moreover, in your example, `result` looks like a local variable, so the refactoring should typically not affect more than one file.

> The job of a Web API controller isn't to know the details about what business logic is going on; it's just to invoke something and return it.

If `var result = mediator.Send(query).Result;` is a generic, reusable piece of code, processing different kinds queries and maybe returning different things, then this line is fine. However, if that would be your situation, then you probably would not have asked the question in the first place. I guess in this case, the query is always an `accountFilter`, and the result is always an `accountDetails`, and as long as that is true, your variable names should express that.

Of course, as I wrote above, if the next line in your function is just `return result;`, the unspecific name is ok.

> If you really want to know what the line of code is doing, you can look at the context surrounding it.

Seriously? You want another maintenance programmer to decipher the surrounding context first to understand what is going on, whilst by simply picking a better name could save him half an hour of brain work? Be aware, in six months *you* might be the maintenance programmer for this line of code, and it will look to you as if someone else has written it first place. What would you prefer in that situation? A variable name telling you what it represents, or one for which you have to analyse the code first to be sure what it does?

So except for very simplistic cases where the whole function looks like

```
 AccountDetails GetAccountDetails(Query query)
 {
    var result = mediator.Send(query).Result;
    return result;
 }
```

you will probably be better off to use a more specific name (though - even for such a simple function - a parameter name  like `accountFilter` instead of query will increase the readability heavily, and in this example, the `result` parameter is quite useless, I would typically prefer to write `return mediator.Send(accountFilter).Result`).

Comment: In your last example, why even use vague variable names there? If using explicit variable names is less cognitive overhead in complex methods, isn't it also less cognitive overhead in simple methods as well?

Comment: @BobHorn: sure, see my edit.

Comment: I struggled between picking this answer and the other answer. Thank you for your input. I loved this line: "Seriously? You want another maintenance programmer to decipher the surrounding context first to understand what is going on?"

Comment: Following OP's naming convention the method should be called `GetResult`... oh dear... good luck trying to understand the context.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you should prefer descriptive names. But, if the containing method/function is short (a couple of lines), well named, and if it's clear what is it that it returns, then naming the variable "result" is really not a problem.

However, as the method/function becomes bigger and more complex, using a non-descriptive, generic name, becomes more and more problematic.

> The job of a Web API controller isn't to know the details about what business logic is going on; it's just to invoke something and return it.

Well... the name of the variable should indicate what the object/value obtain represents in the context of the surrounding code. If the name of the containing method is something like GetAccountDetails, then your argument doesn't really apply, and the name "accountDetails" is perfectly fine - *but*, if you still feel that the controller knows implementation details it shouldn't, then your abstractions in the bussiness logic layer could be a bit off.

Answer (score 3):

Are ***vague*** names more maintainable?

**No.** It may be that there is no additional useful information to convey, but that calls for a *generic* name instead. Don't confuse everyone by not saying what you mean.

Are ***generic*** names more maintainable?

**Depends.** Is that generic name conveying everything important, or is there more useful information you could put into the name without getting too verbose or even repetitive?

Are ***specific*** names more maintainable?

**Depends.** Don't be overspecific or repetitive.

As always, context is king.

Answer (score 1):

Playing devil's advocate to an extent, but lets consider the following code:

```
public List<Model> getModelsByTypeId(string modelTypeId)
{
    var result = new List<Model>();
    var dataset = myloverlysqlhelper(this.sqlForGettingModels, modelTypeId);
    //loop dataset and populate result...
    return result;
}
```

Here I have used 'generic' variable names instead of say `modelResult` and `modelDataset` and the meaning is made completely clear by the context.

I can copy and past the code into a dozen other similar functions and not have to edit the name in each.

But! even here I am still using `modelTypeId` instead of `id` or some more generic name. You could argue that the function name gives you enough context that `id` is justifiable, but would you ever put `queryParameter`? no, that wouldn't make any sense at all.

So, in summary, yes context allows you to be a little generic, you don't want to be having `for(var integerWhichIAmCountingUpTo10 = 0;....` but generally a little extra description helps.

Comment: Copy and paste? You made the code general via the names and design.  Go all out and make it completely reusable via generics and/or delegates. I imagine you would do this, but you did say "copy and paste".

Comment: generic repos are bad

Comment: I would say all repositories are bad, but it was about variables. Your point in the answer is correct, I just would not promote copy and paste.

Comment: copy and paste with minor changes is sometimes better than making things super generic

Comment: I guess the point is that, the one-sentence mentioning of "copy and past (sic)" seems to distract (or even ruin) an otherwise good answer. I would rephrase your answer in this way: for small functions, the function name already provides some context; function arguments can use a little bit of extra naming juice (for context) if that helps further reduce confusion, or to promote consistency (uniformity, pattern) in the user's brain. In a small function like this, bikeshedding about local variable name is nobody's business. Functions longer than 10 lines of code need written more carefully.

Comment: because its a local variable, (which it needs to be in the context of the answer) unless you copy and paste there is no benefit to the more generic name. If you have 10 getModelbySomethingAndSomething getAllDifferentModel etc etc then the generic name saves you renaming (and thinking up 10 non generic names)

Answer (score 0):

My answer would depend on the complexity of the code.

I've used `result`, but generally in contexts where the code is simple and/or the life of the variable is short.

If the code is complex (which it sounds like it's not in this case) vague variable names make it harder for the reader to understand the code because they have to waste cognitive overhead on remembering what the variable actually is.